# SCSI RAID 5 configuration probabbly lost: is it a good idea to write-protect disks?

Tags: raid5, scsi

I need to restart a Dell Precision 670 server that includes a Dell 320 / DC SCSI RAID adapter.

The server was shut down for 7 years and the BIOS setup was lost.

I have 3 disks configured in RAID5 (it's written on disks), their model is seagate cheetah 10k7, the user told me that SCSI IDs have not been changed.

Is it a good idea to write-protect disks with jumpers until I find the correct BIOS configuration, or can it cause other problems?

If the disks are not write-protected, are there any risks of overwriting the RAID configuration on the disks?

The operating system is RHEL 4.x.

Comment: Write protect disks? What sort of damage are you expecting someone to do?! If that person is that dangerous, should they even be near the machine at all?

Comment: Write-protect disks to avoid destroying disk RAID configuration when starting the server and reconfiguring the BIOS by trying many options. If the operating system boot is successful, the BIOS setup is correct and I can reconfigure the disks for writing. Is this a stupid method?

Comment: You just want to protect against mistakes? OK, then just make raw image copies of the disks.